# Writing a XML linter in PHP, but both XMLReader and XML parser can't handle parsing error

Tags: php, xml, xmlreader

I'm tasked to write a XML linter in PHP8 and it shall server as a web API. This XML linter must work in verbose mode that goes through the whole document and log every error found (up to 1000 errors) with line number (yes I know XML can one single-line but it's a mandatory requirement).

In other words, I need a XML reader/parser module that can:

1. [mandatory] process medium to large size XML documents (100MB~1GB).
2. [mandatory] surpass error and keep parsing, if possible.
3. [mandatory] write my own checker code to validate the value of TEXT node.
4. [mandatory] get line number of current node.

But after some study, none of the PHP built-in XML extensions can satisfy these requirements.

For example here is a "bad" XML that the closing tags at line 5 (`<AuthorityCode>...</Authority>`) & line 11 (`<LastUpdateTime>...</LastUpdate>`) mismatches with starting tags:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<FacilityList>
    <UpdateTime>2022-09-09T08:00:00+08:00</UpdateTime>
    <UpdateInterval type="SEMIAUTO">-1</UpdateInterval>
    <AuthorityCode>CA</Authority>
    <Facility>
        <FacilityID>NFB-NR-P00501-013037-SN-S9K6VPJ36-0002</FacilityID>
        <FacilityClass>01</FacilityClass>
        <FacilityType>003</FacilityType>
        <LocationType>1</LocationType>
        <LastUpdateTime>2022-10-04T13:00:00+08:00</LastUpdate>
    </Facility>
</FacilityList>
```

The `xmllint` tool from `libxml` will show all errors at line 5 and line 11, but both **XMLReader** and **XML Parser** will just stop at line 5 and won't go further, and I can't find a way to bypass it. Yes I've already set the `XML_PARSE_RECOVER` flag in `XMLReader`:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);   
$parser = new XMLReader();
$parser->open($filename,null,LIBXML_NOERROR|LIBXML_NOWARNING|1);
```

And it doesn't work (PHP 8.2.6).

Did I do something wrong, or it's just not possible to do what I wanted using built-in XMLReader / XML expat parser ?
The **DOMDocument** can process and report both errors, but I don't want to load the whole 1GB data into memory.

[EDIT]
No I'm not asking for a 3rd party products but just want to know what should I do with PHP built-in functions. Like some sort of magic options in `XMLReader` / XML expat parser, or example codes to make `DOMDocument` parsing based on partial data from a streaming source. Or at least just tell me that "**you can't do this in PHP**".

I've already checked many 3rd party libraries but none of them can do what I wanted. They either just provide a wrapper of XML expat parser, or relies on `DOMDocument` to load everything into memory in the beginning.

=====

BTW, is there any reliable way to get line number from **XMLReader** ? Yes I know the `XMLReader::expand()` trick but it just doesn't work when the XML is badly formatted (such as mission closing tag).

Trying to count the number of `\n` and `\r` by myself doesn't work either, because `XMLReader` doesn't report anything before `<FacilityList>`: the `<?xml version="1.0"?>` and the following whitespace are totally ignored.

Comment: I assume from this you're seeking a recommendation for a third-party product, but that's off-topic here. See [help/on-topic]

Comment: @Tangentially Perpendicular
I'd be more grateful if you can tell me what should I do so that PHP built-in XMLReader or XML Expat parser can fulfill my needs, or just tell me that "**it's not possible to do so in PHP**" so that I shall discuss with the  client about the requirements. I've already checked at least 10+ different 3rd party libraries but none of them can do what I wanted. They either can't parse past error in stream mode, or relies on DOMDocument to do everything.

Comment: Xml is not valid.  The closing tag must be exactly the same as opening tag : <AuthorityCode>CA</Authority>  Code is missing in closing tag.

Comment: @jdweng Yes and my task is writing a tool to find out such error in a document. We called such tool a "**linter**" and I believe I've stated that in the title. And if you look carefully there is another bug at line 11, as stated in the sentence **right above** the XML block. And the problem is, both XMLReader and XML expat parser will just stop at line 5 and won't proceed to pick the other bug at line 11 and I don't know how to force them recover from error. So now if you know the answer, please tell me.

Comment: This is not a parsing error.  The input is bad.  As I said the XML is not valid and you cannot recover from these types of errors.

Comment: @jdweng `xmllint` from `libxml2` can recover from such error, as well as PHP `DOMDocument` extension. Both can find errors on line 5 **and** line 11 in one single error report. And **that's all what I wanted**. The problem is, I'm dealing with gigabytes of data and I don't want to load everything into a DOM object, and PHP doesn't provide low level API to `libxml2`. My last resort is calling `xmllint` via `shell_exec()` but I don't want to do that, since the target platform of Web API hosting server could be Windows.

Comment: The solution is to get the people who generated the bad xml to fix the problems.  Data should always be verified before sending out to the public.  Once you get a good xml file you can uses a library like XmlReader that is designed to handle huge xml files.

Comment: @jdweng ...and my job is **making a tool** to tell **that guy** to fix his god darn XML **BEFORE** it's published to "the public", along with a bug report telling him where the problems are. And I'm supposed to pick out as many bugs as possible. Maybe you'd be satisfied with a compiler that stops at the first error in source codes, but the client is asking for more.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do, but there are limits to what you can do.  There are two basic types of errors 1) XML Structure 2) XML Schema You have a error in the structure when the open and close tags do not match. and this type of error is hard to recover from.  In college I took CS201.  We were using punch cards and sometimes it took hours to get results.  The professor had two input files online that we used for testing.  One with no error and the other with errors.  When I got down I had a program with over 500 cards and more than that in the circular container (garbage).

Comment: @jdweng so basically you're telling me "**you can't do that in PHP**". Fine. That's also an acceptable answer and I'm going to negotiate with the client. Guess I should post this as the answer and maybe someone knows the solution will argue with that. Should have do that in the beginning.

Comment: I didn't exactly say that.  There are different layers of errors.  Some that are critical that have to be fixed, and others that less critical that do not need to be immediately fixed.  XML having starting and endings tags being symmetrical is a very critical error that must be fixed immediately.  There is not work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK from the comments from other people, the answer for my question seems to be "**NO YOU CAN'T DO THAT IN PHP**".